# How can I repeat a list a variable number of times

Tags: r

So let's say I have a list

```
x <- as.list(c("john","jerry","james"))
```

And a list of values

```
y <- as.list(c(8,5,10))
```

And I want to loop through the first element of x, the first element of y amount of times and add a suffix at the end.  So for the element john, it'd be john_1,john_2...john_8.  Then jerry would be jerry_1,jerry_2...jerry_5. And james_1,james_2,...,james_10

Here's what I've tried that doesn't work

```
z <- lapply(x, function(i){paste(i,"_",rep(max))})
```

but that doesn't give me what I want.

Maybe, I shouldn't be using lapply or some version of map* instead, but haven't worked on those.

Comment: `as.list(c(…))` => `list(…)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An idea via base R,

```
Map(function(x, y)paste0(x, '_', seq(y)), x, y)

#[[1]]
#[1] "john_1" "john_2" "john_3" "john_4" "john_5" "john_6" "john_7" "john_8"

#[[2]]
#[1] "jerry_1" "jerry_2" "jerry_3" "jerry_4" "jerry_5"

#[[3]]
# [1] "james_1"  "james_2"  "james_3"  "james_4"  "james_5"  "james_6"  "james_7"  "james_8"  "james_9"  "james_10"
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. I'll mark as answer when it allows me.

Answer (score 3):

Or:

```
x <- as.list(c("john","jerry","james"))
y <- as.list(c(8,5,10))

lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) paste0(x[[i]], "_", seq_len(y[[i]])))

# [[1]]
# [1] "john_1" "john_2" "john_3" "john_4" "john_5" "john_6" "john_7" "john_8"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "jerry_1" "jerry_2" "jerry_3" "jerry_4" "jerry_5"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "james_1"  "james_2"  "james_3"  "james_4"  "james_5"  "james_6"  "james_7"  "james_8"  "james_9"  "james_10"
```

Comment: That works as well! Going to mark the first person as correct, but like the lapply version too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok having a single vector for all the values you could do use `paste`, `rep` and `sequence`

```
paste(rep(x, y), sequence(y), sep = "_")

#[1] "john_1"   "john_2"   "john_3"   "john_4" "john_5"   "john_6" "john_7"  "john_8"  
#[9] "jerry_1"  "jerry_2"  "jerry_3"  "jerry_4" "jerry_5"  "james_1"  "james_2"  "james_3" 
#[17] "james_4" "james_5"  "james_6"  "james_7"  "james_8"  "james_9"  "james_10"
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is

```
paste(rep(x, y), unlist(lapply(y, seq)), sep="_")
```